# Insertar un Array en Excel

Tags: c#, array, excel

Estoy trabajando con un array donde `espectador` posee una colección de elementos. Los puedo leer fácilmente con

```
foreach(espectador in TwitchJSON)
    { Console.Writeline("-->" + espectador); }
```

> Output
>
> ```
>   --> Maria
>
>   --> José
>
>   --> Rick
> ```

Mi problema es que necesito exportar esa colección a una hoja excel, he intentado usar:

```
Worksheet.Range["A1"].Text = "espectador";
```

Pero el Array se une por completo

> MariaJoséRick

Comment: De lo que dices deduzco que `espectador` no es un array, sino un string que contendrá retornos de carro.  Excel no debe estar interpretando esos retornos de carro y por eso te lo junta (creo recordar que hay que configurar la celda como multilinea o algo asi para que lo acepte, no soy muy experto en excel)

Comment: Tras releer tu pregunta, lo que es un array es `TwitchJSON`, no `espectador`. `espectador` es solo el valor que va tomando en el `foreach`. Asi que creo que en todo caso a la celda excel debes pasarle `TwitchJSON`, no `espectador`.

Comment: @pikoh muchas gracias tienes razón lo pondré en practica